Using listadd from etoolbox to build a list of names
I would like to create a list of people's names. However my attempt is not working
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{person}
\setcounter{person}{0}

\newcommand{\people}{}
\newcommand{\firstperson}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\anotherperson}[1]{, #1}

\newcommand{\addperson}[1]{
    \stepcounter{person}
    \ifnumequal{\value{person}}{1}
        {\listadd{\people}{\firstperson{#1}}}
        {\listadd{\people}{\anotherperson{#1}}}
}

\begin{document}

\addperson{Alice}
\addperson{Bob}
%\addperson{Charles}

\people

\end{document}

This displays 'Alice' in text mode, then 'Bob' in math mode. If I try to add 'Charles', compilation fails, indicating that a dollar sign was missing and has been inserted.
What's wrong?

You can't just use the list like that directly because it uses | internally to separate the items. You need instead to use one of the loop-type macros etoolbox provides to iterate through the list. This is made explicit in a footnote in the documentation: Note that you may not typeset a list by saying \listname. Use \show instead to inspect the list. (page 29) Honestly, there are better ways to construct and deploy lists these days.

I see. Thanks. I completely misunderstood what \listadd is intended for.

It would be better to answer your own question rather than adding your answer into the question, which kind of screws up the Q&A format ;).

Yes, but your answer is more helpful. So, I will accept it. I edited the original question before your detailed answer appeared. My edit doesn't duplicate your stuff, so I think it can stay.

You can do both. Your solution doesn't duplicate anything in my answer, as you say. So it is a different answer. But I'm not dogmatic about it. It's your question ;). It just makes it easier for other people with the same problem to find different ways of solving it if the solutions are posted as answers. And yes, we posted at the same time. Your edit appeared after I'd answered, but my answer would have appeared after you edited.

If within your code, uncommenting the Charles line, you replace \people with \show\people, you get on the console
> \people=macro:
->\firstperson {Alice}|\anotherperson {Bob}|\anotherperson {Charles}|.

which is definitely not what you expect: the \listadd command literally adds what's in the second argument to the macro given as the first argument. Besides, the | you see in the message is not really an ordinary character, but a | with category code 3 instead of the standard 12.
This explains the mysterious “Missing $ inserted” messages, because a character token of category code 3 starts math mode. etoolbox uses this as a separator because only a devious user would produce such a token in ordinary input.
Your code should be
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\addperson}[1]{\listadd{\people}{#1}}
\newcommand{\printlist}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{##1\renewcommand{\do}[1]{, ####1}}%
  \dolistloop{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\addperson{Alice}
\addperson{Bob}
\addperson{Charles}

\printlist{\people}

\end{document}


However, as you see, this is very cumbersome. The \dolistloop command applies \do to each item in the list and this command has to be defined to perform the desired job. In this case it has to print the first item and redefine itself to print the item preceded by “comma and space”.
The alternative of doing
\newcommand*{\people}{}
\newcommand{\addperson}[1]{%
  \ifx\people\empty
    \def\people{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\people\expandafter{\people, #1}%
  \fi
}

would allow you to issue \people and get the same output as before, but with the disadvantage that you're stuck with the list in that form and cannot process it differently.
A different approach where you can manage any number of lists without the need to invent new command names.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_blair_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_blair_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\uselist}{O{,~} m o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #3 }
   {
    \seq_use:cn { l_blair_list_#2_seq } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_map_inline:cn { l_blair_list_#2_seq } { #3 }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_count:c { l_blair_list_#1_seq }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{people}

\begin{document}

\addtolist{people}{Alice}
\addtolist{people}{Bob, Charles}

\uselist{people}

\uselist[--]{people}

The list \texttt{people} has \countlist{people} items.

\addtolist{people}{Denise}

\begin{enumerate}
\uselist{people}[\item #1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


You see that you can add more than one item at a time. The \uselist command has two optional arguments and a mandatory one (the list name). If the trailing optional argument is not present, the first one is used (default “comma and space”) as separator between items.
The trailing optional argument is a template, where the current item is denoted by #1.
With \countlist you access the number of items.
In this implementation, addition of items is local, respecting groups. If you need global assignments, here's the variant.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_blair_list_#1_seq }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_blair_list_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\uselist}{O{,~} m o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #3 }
   {
    \seq_use:cn { g_blair_list_#2_seq } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_map_inline:cn { g_blair_list_#2_seq } { #3 }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countlist}{m}
 {
  \seq_count:c { g_blair_list_#1_seq }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{people}

\begin{document}

\addtolist{people}{Alice}
\addtolist{people}{Bob, Charles}

\uselist{people}

\uselist[--]{people}

The list \texttt{people} has \countlist{people} items.

\addtolist{people}{Denise}

\begin{enumerate}
\uselist{people}[\item #1]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

Basically, the only changes are in using \seq_gput_right:cn (global addition) and in the naming of the sequence, with prefix g_ rather than l_.

It seems I did not understand what \listadd is supposed to do.
The following produces the outcome I wanted
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{person}
\setcounter{person}{0}

\newcommand{\people}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addperson}[1]{
    \stepcounter{person}
    \ifnumequal{\value{person}}{1}
        {\g@addto@macro\people{#1}}
        {\g@addto@macro\people{, #1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addperson{Alice}
\addperson{Bob}
\addperson{Charles}

\people

\end{document}


Thank you! ....
